# Pythonを使いLinkedInからGoogle社員の出身大学の情報を集めたい

Tags: python, web-scraping

プログラミング初心者です。Pyhtonを使い、LinkedInからGoogle社で働いている社員の出身大学のデータを集めたいのですが、スクレイピングを使えばいいのでしょうか？　また、スクレイピングで可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 4):

> Pyhtonを使い、LinkedInからGoogle社で働いている社員の出身大学のデータを集めたいのですが、スクレイピングを使えばいいのでしょうか？　また、スクレイピングで可能でしょうか？

LinkedInの[利用規約](https://jp.linkedin.com/legal/user-agreement?)に「やるべきではないこと」として下記項目が書いてありますので禁止されているようです。

> 本サービスをスクレイピングする目的、またはその他の方法で本サービスからプロフィールおよびその他のデータを複写する目的で、ソフトウェア、デバイス、スクリプト、ロボット、またはその他の方法もしくは手順 (クローラ、ブラウザーのプラグインとアドオン、その他のテクノロジーを含みます) を開発、サポート、または使用すること。

また下記の記述もありますので、データの流用そのものが禁止事項に該当するかと思われます。

> LinkedInの承諾を得ずに、直接または第三者を経由して (検索エンジンなど)、本サービスから入手した情報を複写、使用、開示、または配布すること。